# Typo on CakePHP's HttpSocket class?

Tags: cakephp

I've been having issues when making HTTPS requests to servers via `HttpSocket`. HTTP requests work just fine. Checking the code of that class, I noticed [the following piece starting on line 272](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/http-socket/#l-295) in `HttpSocket`. I'm on the latest 2.04 stable version, btw.

```
if (is_array($this->request['header'])) { 
    if (!empty($this->request['cookies'])) {
        $cookies = $this->buildCookies($this->request['cookies']);
    }
    $schema = '';
    $port = 0;
    if (isset($this->request['uri']['schema'])) {
        $schema = $this->request['uri']['schema'];
    }
    if (isset($this->request['uri']['port'])) {
        $port = $this->request['uri']['port'];
    }
    if (
        ($schema === 'http' && $port != 80) ||
        ($schema === 'https' && $port != 443) ||
        ($port != 80 && $port != 443)
    ) {
        $Host .= ':' . $port;
    }
    $this->request['header'] = array_merge(compact('Host'), $this->request['header']);
}
```

As far as I know, the `request` array never has a `schema` key, although it does have a `scheme` key, as seen [here](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/http-socket/#l-88). It's interesting that it seems that [the code has been like since version 1.0](http://api12.cakephp.org/view_source/http-socket/#l-203) and I couldn't find anything about it on the web. I also changed the letter, just to see if my code worked, but it caused warnings and notices. So... am I missing something?

I wanted to run it by experts, before I started digging deeper into the code. Any help or clarification will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: thats an interesting question - because the official name for it would be "scheme" :)

Comment: I know! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: haha, but even there you can find the word "schema" twice. seems to be  interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is not my first language
But from my understanding of sources like
http://www.englishforums.com/English/SchemaVsScheme/jkwmw/post.htm
and
http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=711283&langid=3
as well as 
http://www.answers.com/topic/scheme / http://www.answers.com/topic/schema
it is indeed a typo.

It should probably be "scheme" because it is not a graphical or "visible" representation but a  logical way of applying sth.
Also the complete framework uses scheme everywhere regarding urls and schema regarding DB table representation.

I opened a ticket:
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/2345-typo-in-httpsocket-class

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure where or how one's supposed to open tickets about the core code. I'll follow it up.

Comment: already made it in the core :) https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/be770bd9b8086d7136ec9a916659dc8e953b2da3